# jsf inputtext doesn't show value from bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the follow situation:

I have a bean that send to form some data, but only in outputlabel the data from the bean is displayed.
I tried to use primefaces, but the same problems persist.
my code:

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{Bean.name}" id="name2" />
<h:inputText value="#{Bean.name}" id="name" />
<p:inputText value="#{Bean.name}" id="name3" />
```

Any idea why?

Comment: You try change #{Bean.name} to #{bean.name}, if not, you need to port you code from bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem.

When I tried show the values, I was trying recover data from database by pass an ajax action. So, When I clicked at button to retrieve the datas, some of my inputText were set as a required. And because this the data is just displaying into label and not inside of inputtext with required. But because ajax, the request were not called correctly.

When I remove the required from inputtext, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should have given the bean's code also, to help us better analyze the problem.

Normally you should check for the following:

1. Check whether you are specifying a correct bean name. Normally
   bean's name is same as that of class, except that first letter
   should be lowercase. In your case it should be `#{bean.name}` or else,
   specify your custom name with `@Named("Bean")`.
2. Check whether the getters and setters such as getName() are properly
   provided. It may happen that you might have **reset** the name property in
   your bean in the get method itself. Because of which first time it
   shows you properly in `outputLabel` and then in next call to getName it may give you null or empty String. To check this, try put your `inputText` tag first, and check.